# How to split up a String of numbers into individual digits and put them into a Linked List?

Tags: java

so I'm implementing an ADT into this Linked List implementation and I need to use constructor chaining which makes my number into a String. Then I have to break it up into separate characters and store them in a a Linked List.

Note: I am using a wrapper class called Node

```
public class Node {
String item;
Node next;

    public Node(String item, Node next) {
            this.item=item;
            this.next=next;
    }
}
```

This is my code so far for trying to split up the String

```
public class LinkBNum implements BNum {
Node myList; 

public LinkBNum() {
  this(0);  

}

public LinkBNum(long a) {
  this(String.valueOf(a));  

}

public LinkBNum(String s) {

    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
       myList = new Node(s.charAt(i),null);
       }       

}
```

How would accomplish splitting my string up and placing it into a Linked List?

Comment: Can you try simple sub string function which gives you one char

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String numAsStr = (new Integer(num)).toString();
int[] digits = new int[numAsStr.length()];
for(int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++)  {
   digits[i] = Character.getNumericValue(numAsStr.charAt(i));
}
```

I just typed this on a 3-inch screen, so forgive a few typos.  :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `s.toCharArray()` function to get the individual characters in a character array

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 public LinkBNum(String s) {

      while (s.length()>0) {
       myList = new Node(s.substring(0, 1),null);
        s=s.substring(1)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public LinkBNum(String s) {

    for(char c : s.toCharArray()) {
       if (null == myList)
           myList = new Node(c,null);
       else
           myList.next = new Node(c,null);//assuming 'next' is accessible here
    }
}
```